# Facebook login API "Can't Load Url: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains"

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hi I am a beginner programmer trying to integrate facebook login in my mobile app. I have read through multiple similar questions but cannot seem to find a solution to the error. I have been following this [javascript facebook login guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_gLILTRD_k) and have **successfully** logged in in through my browser. **However**, I am unable to log in through my mobile app, with the Error  [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZu8h.jpg) : `"Can't Load Url: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains"` I do not own any domains and am using localhost (XAMPP) and Eclipse emulator. Eclipse has also returned several errors like `"Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings"` and `"pub com.android.browser.home: com.android.browser.homepages.Homeprovider"` amongst others
[shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36zCt.jpg)

Here is what my the facebook interface looks like:
Developer pannel
[shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoiUg.jpg)
Valid Oauth settings
[shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MWe2.jpg)

Here is my javascript code:

```
<body>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    //initialize and setup facebook SDK
                      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                        FB.init({
                          appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                          xfbml      : true,
                          version    : 'v2.7'
                        });

                        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                              if (response.status === 'connected') {
                                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are connected';
                                //  console.log('Logged in.');
                              }
                              else if (response.status === 'not_authorized'){
                                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are not logged in';
                              }
                              else{
                                  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML= 'facebook not logged in';
                              }
                            });
                      };

                      (function(d, s, id){
                         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                         js.src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                        //js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


                      function login(){
                          FB.login(function(response){
                              if (response.status === 'connected') {
                                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are connected';
                                    //document.getElementById('login').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                                    //  console.log('Logged in.');
                                  }
                                  else if (response.status === 'not_authorized'){
                                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are not logged in';
                                  }
                                  else{
                                      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML= 'facebook not logged in';
                                  }

                          }, {scope: 'email'});
                      }

                    </script>
                    hi
                    <div id="status"></div>
                    <button onclick="login()">Login</button>

                    </body>
```

Comment: try and check by adding http://localhost as app domain settings in Facebook app page.

Comment: [I have already added them](http://imgur.com/IiHlTLp)  I have also tried using localhost.com for app domain too, but to no avail.

Comment: I had the same problem,

I just added the link of my local adress http://localhost/Facebook%20Login%20Test.html to Site URL in my application setting https://developers.facebook.com/apps.

then it worked fine.

Comment: [I think I have them already here](http://imgur.com/cU5zVg5), were you also trying the FB login on a mobile app? [Here is my whole app settings page](http://imgur.com/IiHlTLp)

Comment: anyone installing the FB login plugin from javascript too?